# Agents Of S.H.I.E.L.D Season 5 - does it spoil Avengers: Infinity War?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, suggested-order, agents-of-shield

I have had the pleasure this last week on catching up on the MCU films that followed *Guardians of The Galaxy: Vol. 2*, *Spider-man: Homecoming*, *Thor: Ragnarok* and *Black Panther*

I have just started watching Season 5 of *Agents Of S.H.E.E.L.D*, now confident that any references to the events of the films I have watched over the last week will now not spoil any story points for me, but the Wikipedia page for [the season] states that  "The end of the season dovetails with events of the film Avengers: Infinity War."

Does it simply lead into the events and revelations of the film or does it actually refer to any of them, such as the strong connection between Season 1 and *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, which would have spoiled the films central twist if the TV show had been seen first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can safely watch Season 5 of *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* without worrying about spoiling the end of *Infinity War*.

There are no spoilers made, and only some *very* vague references to the *beginning* of Infinity War, and none to the movie's climax. The references are slim and not relevant to the plot of the show, and are a lot less tied into the show than the *Winter Soldier* reveals to Season 1 (where they were essential to understanding the plot) or even the vague references to *Thor 2* earlier in that season, where the agents come to play clean-up after the events of the movie.

Go forth and watch safely.

Comment: Thanks for the answers folks - just finished watching it and I am still blarting tears all over the shop. Just have to wait until Christmas to watch 'Infinity War' now...

Answer (score 1):

No.

The only reference made in Agents of SHIELD regarding Infinity War is name-dropping Thanos with a simple "Thanos's forces are attacking the earth as we speak".

It doesn't explore Infinity War plot points because this season was made as a series finale to have a complete ending to the show & its characters in case it wasn't renewed for another season.